# Paypal Subscriptions / Recurring Payments Change Funding Source via API

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

When using Paypal Subscription / Recurring Payments can you allow the user to update or add a new credit card / bank information from your website (i.e. not paypal) and set that as the funding source of the subscription?

As an example: On numerous occasions our users subscription payment fails, either due to a new credit card reissue or a closing of a bank account. When this happens we tell them to login to Paypal and update their credit card info with the new number/date, etc. or add a new cc or bank account and set that as the primary funding source. Most of our users are not tech savvy and so the first question is: What is my paypal login info? (we don't know) If they are able to login, they have to click through several screens to get to the appropriate funding source screen. It is all very difficult for them. So we are looking for a way to streamline the process so that if they are on our site and looking at their account details they can easily change the funding source information.

Is that possible? Any suggestions on how to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you're paying for the 'Direct Recurring Payments' product, then yes, you can take the card data directly on your site and update the recurring payments profile via the UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile API with this new information.

If, however, you're just using Express Checkout with Recurring Payments (or Payments Standard Subscriptions, for that matter), then no, this is not possible. At all.
The best you could is use IPN or GetTransactionDetails to find out the buyer's primary email address, and use that to remind them that "your PayPal account email address registered with us is .......".

Comment: Robert, thank you for the reply. Just to make sure I'm on the same page with you. The Direct Recurring Payments is part of Paypal payments pro (only), right?